# Global variable in ShinyServer

Tags: r, shiny

I just started hacking around with Shiny a few days ago.

In my little toy app, the user types a list of comma-separated numbers into a text area and presses the submit button. It then calculates and displays the sum, mean and median of those numbers.

The shinyServer functions that calculate the sum, mean and median all call a function named my_array() that uses strsplit to separate the numbers at the commas and returns a numeric list.

Rather than call my_array() three times, I'd like to call my_array() once after the Submit button has been clicked and save the result globally. Then I'll use that global list to calculate sum, mean and median.

Can someone clue me in as to how I can call my_array() once after submit is hit, and save the result in a global variable? Nothing I'm trying works, and the examples I've seen don't seem to address what I need.

Thanks.

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    my_array <- reactive ({
        number_array <- strsplit(input$text, ",")
        as.numeric(number_array[[1]])
    })

    my_sum <- reactive({
        sum(my_array())
    })

    my_mean <- reactive({
        val <- mean(my_array(), na.rm=TRUE)

        if (is.nan(val)) {
            val = ""
        } else {
            val
        }
    })

    my_median <- reactive({
        val <- median(my_array(), na.rm=TRUE)

        if (is.na(val)) {
            val = ""
        } else {
            val
        }
    })

    output$sum <- renderText({ my_sum() })
    output$mean <- renderText({ my_mean() })
    output$median <- renderText({ my_median() })   
})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Average Calculator"),

    tags$style(type="text/css", "textarea {width:100%}"),
    tags$textarea(id = 'text', placeholder = 'Enter comma-separated numbers here', rows = 8, ""),
    submitButton("Submit"),

    hr(),

    fluidRow(column(2, strong("Sum:"), align="right"), column(3, textOutput("sum"))),
    fluidRow(column(2, strong("Mean:"), align="right"), column(3, textOutput("mean"))),
    fluidRow(column(2, strong("Median:"), align="right"), column(3, textOutput("median"))),

))
```

Comment: Ignoring obsolete comma your code seems to work just fine. Could you clarify what exactly are you trying to achieve? `my_array` is calculated once after each submit and cached so there is no problem here.

Answer (score 0):

As @zero323 said, the result is already cached, but if you really want to, you can use `observeEvent()` to fire off when you press the button:

```
observeEvent(input$your_button_id, {
        number_array <- strsplit(input$text, ",")
        as.numeric(number_array[[1]])
})
```

This will fire only once every time you press the button. You might also want to check for `NULL` or `""` variables.

Comment: I didn't realize it was cached. Are you saying that it doesn't do a strsplit each time I call my_array()?

Comment: Ah, OK. I just put a little debug statement in my_array() and you are correct, it only gets called once rather than three times when the Submit button is pressed. Thanks. Question answered!